# Multiple doubleClick ads not showing in amp pages

Tags: ads, amp-html, double-click, amp-ad

I'm adding 3 doubleClick ads to an amp page as following with same data-slot it shows only 1 ad instead of 3, sometimes it shows 2 instead of 3 and ads not displayed shows white or same as the attached images any idea about this issue :

```
<div class="ad-box">
    <div class="amp-ad-container">
        <amp-ad width="300" height="250" type="doubleclick" data-slot="/6355419/Travel/Europe/France/Paris">
        </amp-ad>
    </div>
    <span class="ad-text">Advertisement</span>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: please share fiddle

Comment: did you solve this problem @allo

Comment: @Mr.O still not solved